# uploadify in firefox is not working

Tags: uploadify

I have the uploadify control in my app. When running in IE, everything is ok. but when in firefox, it is giving the error:

uploadify flashVer.split is not a function

has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is quite old, but i had the same issue.

this seems to be a bug with flash that cause it to ignore browser session, instead it pulls cookie from IE no-matter what browser your using, which causes the problem,

since Uploadify uses flash so it wont work in FF or chrome, the bug is not fixed yet, however you might find this URL helpful for some workarounds.

http://joncahill.zero41.com/2009/11/problems-with-uploadify-aspnet-mvc-and.html